# How to remove one of owner from db in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rds

How can I remove this user from having owner permissions , so i can drop the user?

```
mydb=> \ddp
                    Default access privileges
    Owner     | Schema |   Type   |      Access privileges
--------------+--------+----------+------------------------------
 postgres     | public | sequence | read_write=rwU/postgres     +
              |        |          | reuser=rU/postgres
 postgres     | public | table    | read_only=r/postgres        +
              |        |          | read_write=arwdDxt/postgres +
              |        |          | reuser=arwd/postgres        +
              |        |          | dev_role=arwDxt/postgres
 foo | public | table    | dev_role=arwDxt/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can not drop the table , you need to change the OWNER of the table .

You can choose another user or the database master user `postgres`

example :

```
ALTER TABLE public.table  OWNER TO postgres ;
```